# If a question is both up and down voted, how does the visibility work?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes, upvotes

According to the description in privileges,

> When you vote down, you are nudging that content "down" the page, so it will be seen by fewer people.

and

> When you vote up, you are moving that content "up" so it will be seen by more people

If a question has equal number of up and down votes will the question be seen by fewer people or more people or does it behave as if there are no votes cast?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In terms of the effect on "visibility" or page location, the total score is all that matters; it is as if no votes were cast. In fact, until you can see the split vote totals, you'll never see the difference between a +5/-5 post and a 0/0 post.

Because the reputation effect is different (+10 for up (+5 on questions), -2 for down), the posting user will notice a difference over having no votes cast (their rep will go up 8 * upvotes (on an answer), assuming even voting).

Comment: Note that as the quality project progresses, more factors will determine what gets visibility when, or even _if_ in some cases. I'm going to write up a high level overview of how that's going to work, but it's going to take a few hours.

Comment: Users without enough rep can see `http://site.stackexchange.com/posts/xxxx/timeline` where `xxxx` represents the post ID of a **question** and manually calculate the vote counts of both the question and its answers. The decision to enable the click functionality for 1k+ users only is for technical reasons, not philosophical reasons (too many people doing it at the same time can lead to a DoS attack, but leaving the manual method in still allows <1k users to see it).

Answer (score 15):

Another thing to note is that when you get to 1000 rep on a Stack Exchange site, clicking the votes of a post will show you the ups vs downs:

<kbd>[image: Up v down]</kbd>

Comment: I've seen a few people post screen shots of the split view, but never knew this is how you saw it. TIL.

Comment: @TomHart It actually only shows that view when you click on the vote number. Otherwise it just shows the total like normal. Actually, in your case it seems you already have the reputation required to view this information yourself, try it out!

Comment: Link to the relevant permission: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean, I never realized I just clicked on the number to get the split view.